# How much overhead does an Ajax request have

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, networking

I'm working on a web app that needs to process large amounts of data from the server.

The data can be "streamed" and processed in chunks, so to make it faster I break the data up into packets and download each packet with ajax.

I use javascript promises to send the next ajax request right when the previous one receives it's data.

Each packet is about 300KB and there are normally 20 of them in total.

Now my question is, when I don't have the packets broken up (ie I download a single 6MB file) it takes my browser/network about 4 seconds to do it.

However when I break it up into packets it takes the browser about 8 seconds to download all the packets even though the file size is ultimately the same.

I expected there to be some overhead from each request sending new http headers ect... but to be twice as slow was quite a shock.

I tried moving the ajax requests onto a web worker thinking the main thread was possibly delaying them, but the same thing happens.

Is there anyway to speed up this process, or are there any javascript protocols that would keep the connection open.

I know the browser can do this with video streaming, but I wouldn't know how to use that protocol with binary packets.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the Network tab in Chrome web developer tools when you are downloading the 20 "packets".
From that you should be able to see what the slow down is and help diagnose.
Blur out any sensitive data in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe by default TCP connections in the browser are also subject to TCP congestion controls.

"Slow Start" for example ramps up the rate at which data is read/sent, so not to overwhelm the server and get a baseline of what traffic load the server can handle.

If you break up your 6MB request into many requests, it's possible your paying the "slow start" penalty on each request.

More info here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control

You could try turning on keep-alive headers on the server and see if this improves things.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I'm using nginx as my server, and keep alive is enabled by default. But I was thinking along the same lines of some sort of congestion control algorithm interfering with the packets. I'm gonna read those links you sent me and I'll post a screen shot of my network tab when I get a chance.\